# Can't close a cursor, end a loop, or end a procedure in Oracle Database 11g Express Edition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I can't get this script to work. I am trying to retrieve and output the item-number, description, storehouse number, and unit price of every item stored in I_CATEGORY. I need to close the loop, the cursor, and end the procedure. I keep getting PLS-00103 on all three.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DISP_CATEGORY(I_CATEGORY IN ITEM.CATEGORY) AS

    I_ITEM_NUM ITEM.ITEM_NUM%TYPE;
    I_DESCRIPTION ITEM.DESCRIPTION%TYPE;
    I_STOREHOUSE ITEM.STOREHOUSE%TYPE;
    I_PRICE ITEM.PRICE%TYPE;

    CURSOR CUSTOMCATEGORY IS
    SELECT ITEM_NUM, DESCRIPTION, STOREHOUSE, PRICE
    FROM ITEM
    WHERE CATEGORY = I_CATEGORY

    BEGIN

    OPEN CUSTOMCATEGORY

    LOOP
      FETCH CUSTOMCATEGORY INTO I_ITEM_NUM, I_DESCRIPTION, I_STOREHOUSE, I_PRICE;
      EXIT WHEN CUSTOMCATEGORY%NOTFOUND;
    EXIT LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: You need semicolons at the end of the cursor declaration and the open command.  You need "END LOOP" instead of "EXIT LOOP".

Comment: Thank you! But now it has given me this error: 
Error at line 18: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FETCH" when expecting one of the following: constant exception <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national character nchar 0.01 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DISP_CATEGORY(I_CATEGORY IN ITEM.CATEGORY) AS

I_ITEM_NUM ITEM.ITEM_NUM%TYPE;
I_DESCRIPTION ITEM.DESCRIPTION%TYPE;
I_STOREHOUSE ITEM.STOREHOUSE%TYPE;
I_PRICE ITEM.PRICE%TYPE;

CURSOR CUSTOMCATEGORY IS
SELECT ITEM_NUM, DESCRIPTION, STOREHOUSE, PRICE   
FROM ITEM
WHERE CATEGORY = I_CATEGORY ;  -- missing comma

BEGIN

  OPEN CUSTOMCATEGORY ;

  LOOP
    FETCH CUSTOMCATEGORY INTO I_ITEM_NUM, I_DESCRIPTION, I_STOREHOUSE, I_PRICE;
    EXIT WHEN CUSTOMCATEGORY%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;  -- not exit loop
```

END;